# Convertion of multiply imputed data from wide to long format and back to class mids does not work

Tags: pivot, tidyverse, imputation, r-mice

I performed multiple imputation on my data set (longitudinal study) in wide format. For some analyses I need the data to be in long format.

So I used mice::complete and tidyverse:pivot_longer (see below) which worked out so far. But afterwards mice:as.mids does not work out.

This is a reduced version of the multiply imputed data (originally m= 100, here only m= 5):

```
structure(list(.imp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .id = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L), vp_code = c("AD2803", 
"CN1010", "DI2402", "EI1803", "ER0201", "FA0206", "IA0902", "II1812", 
"IO2107", "IU0712", "NK1104", "NO0501", "OA0308", "OU0712", "RD2711", 
"UU0411", "AO2409", "EP0910", "IA1103", "IE2102", "IH2702", "IP0108", 
"IP2008", "IT0401", "IZ2506", "OI1408", "OR0601", "OR2407", "RK1501", 
"SE0610", "TO2109", "TR2408", "AC1407", "AE0408", "AH3003", "CO1605", 
"EI0612", "ET0511", "EZ1909", "II0909", "II3010", "IT0605", "LC2301", 
"LI1906", "LI3103", "MR2402", "NÖ1702", "NO1711", "NO2609", "RT1109", 
"UO1103", "DF1411", "DR2110", "EI1406", "IA2103", "IC2204", "II2611", 
"IM1703", "JO0704", "LO0902", "NA2201", "NE0302", "NÖ2112", "NP1906", 
"OR1011", "PI3103", "TE2712", "YA3011", "AD2803", "CN1010", "DI2402", 
"EI1803", "ER0201", "FA0206", "IA0902", "II1812", "IO2107", "IU0712", 
"NK1104", "NO0501", "OA0308", "OU0712", "RD2711", "UU0411", "AO2409", 
"EP0910", "IA1103", "IE2102", "IH2702", "IP0108", "IP2008", "IT0401", 
"IZ2506", "OI1408", "OR0601", "OR2407", "RK1501", "SE0610", "TO2109", 
"TR2408", "AC1407", "AE0408", "AH3003", "CO1605", "EI0612", "ET0511", 
"EZ1909", "II0909", "II3010", "IT0605", "LC2301", "LI1906", "LI3103", 
"MR2402", "NÖ1702", "NO1711", "NO2609", "RT1109", "UO1103", "DF1411", 
"DR2110", "EI1406", "IA2103", "IC2204", "II2611", "IM1703", "JO0704", 
"LO0902", "NA2201", "NE0302", "NÖ2112", "NP1906", "OR1011", "PI3103", 
"TE2712", "YA3011", "AD2803", "CN1010", "DI2402", "EI1803", "ER0201", 
"FA0206", "IA0902", "II1812", "IO2107", "IU0712", "NK1104", "NO0501", 
"OA0308", "OU0712", "RD2711", "UU0411", "AO2409", "EP0910", "IA1103", 
"IE2102", "IH2702", "IP0108", "IP2008", "IT0401", "IZ2506", "OI1408", 
"OR0601", "OR2407", "RK1501", "SE0610", "TO2109", "TR2408", "AC1407", 
"AE0408", "AH3003", "CO1605", "EI0612", "ET0511", "EZ1909", "II0909", 
"II3010", "IT0605", "LC2301", "LI1906", "LI3103", "MR2402", "NÖ1702", 
"NO1711", "NO2609", "RT1109", "UO1103", "DF1411", "DR2110", "EI1406", 
"IA2103", "IC2204", "II2611", "IM1703", "JO0704", "LO0902", "NA2201", 
"NE0302", "NÖ2112", "NP1906", "OR1011", "PI3103", "TE2712", "YA3011", 
"AD2803", "CN1010", "DI2402", "EI1803", "ER0201", "FA0206", "IA0902", 
"II1812", "IO2107", "IU0712", "NK1104", "NO0501", "OA0308", "OU0712", 
"RD2711", "UU0411", "AO2409", "EP0910", "IA1103", "IE2102", "IH2702", 
"IP0108", "IP2008", "IT0401", "IZ2506", "OI1408", "OR0601", "OR2407", 
"RK1501", "SE0610", "TO2109", "TR2408", "AC1407", "AE0408", "AH3003", 
"CO1605", "EI0612", "ET0511", "EZ1909", "II0909", "II3010", "IT0605", 
"LC2301", "LI1906", "LI3103", "MR2402", "NÖ1702", "NO1711", "NO2609", 
"RT1109", "UO1103", "DF1411", "DR2110", "EI1406", "IA2103", "IC2204", 
"II2611", "IM1703", "JO0704", "LO0902", "NA2201", "NE0302", "NÖ2112", 
"NP1906", "OR1011", "PI3103", "TE2712", "YA3011", "AD2803", "CN1010", 
"DI2402", "EI1803", "ER0201", "FA0206", "IA0902", "II1812", "IO2107", 
"IU0712", "NK1104", "NO0501", "OA0308", "OU0712", "RD2711", "UU0411", 
"AO2409", "EP0910", "IA1103", "IE2102", "IH2702", "IP0108", "IP2008", 
"IT0401", "IZ2506", "OI1408", "OR0601", "OR2407", "RK1501", "SE0610", 
"TO2109", "TR2408", "AC1407", "AE0408", "AH3003", "CO1605", "EI0612", 
"ET0511", "EZ1909", "II0909", "II3010", "IT0605", "LC2301", "LI1906", 
"LI3103", "MR2402", "NÖ1702", "NO1711", "NO2609", "RT1109", "UO1103", 
"DF1411", "DR2110", "EI1406", "IA2103", "IC2204", "II2611", "IM1703", 
"JO0704", "LO0902", "NA2201", "NE0302", "NÖ2112", "NP1906", "OR1011", 
"PI3103", "TE2712", "YA3011", "AD2803", "CN1010", "DI2402", "EI1803", 
"ER0201", "FA0206", "IA0902", "II1812", "IO2107", "IU0712", "NK1104", 
"NO0501", "OA0308", "OU0712", "RD2711", "UU0411", "AO2409", "EP0910", 
"IA1103", "IE2102", "IH2702", "IP0108", "IP2008", "IT0401", "IZ2506", 
"OI1408", "OR0601", "OR2407", "RK1501", "SE0610", "TO2109", "TR2408", 
"AC1407", "AE0408", "AH3003", "CO1605", "EI0612", "ET0511", "EZ1909", 
"II0909", "II3010", "IT0605", "LC2301", "LI1906", "LI3103", "MR2402", 
"NÖ1702", "NO1711", "NO2609", "RT1109", "UO1103", "DF1411", "DR2110", 
"EI1406", "IA2103", "IC2204", "II2611", "IM1703", "JO0704", "LO0902", 
"NA2201", "NE0302", "NÖ2112", "NP1906", "OR1011", "PI3103", "TE2712", 
"YA3011"), ZB_1 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, 4, 3, 2, NA, 1.5, 2, NA, 
1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2.5, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 
1.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.75, 1, NA, 2.75, 3.5, NA, 1.5, 
3, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2.75, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 2, 
3.5, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 
1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 3.5, 
1.5, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 2.75, 1, 3, 2.75, 3.5, 
3, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2.75, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 
2, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3, 1.5, 2, 4, 
3, 2, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 
1, 1, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.75, 1, 
1, 2.75, 3.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2.75, 1.5, 1, 
1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1, 
3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2.5, 3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 3.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
2.5, 2.75, 1, 1, 2.75, 3.5, 1, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2.5, 
2.75, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 
3, 2.5, 2, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
NA, 2, 2.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 3, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 
2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 3, 2.75, 1, 3, 2.75, 3.5, 1, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 2, 
1, 3.5, 1, 3, 2.75, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 
2.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, NA, 2, 2.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, 3, 1.5, 
1.5, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 2.75, 1, 3, 2.75, 3.5, 3, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.75, 1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2.75, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 
2.5, 2, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 2), ZB_2 = c(3, 3, 2, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
NA, 3, NA, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, NA, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 
NA, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25, 2, NA, NA, 1.25, NA, 2.5, 1, 
1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, NA, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 
3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 
4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 1, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1.75, 3, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 
3, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 
1.25, 2, 3, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 1, 1.5, 
2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1.25, 1, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 
3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25, 2, 3, 3, 
1.25, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, NA, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
1, 2.5, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25, 2, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 1, 2.5, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2.5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 
2.5, 1, 1.5, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 1, 1.25, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1.75, 3, 1.5, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2.5, 4, 
2.5, 3, 2), ZB_3 = c(3, NA, 4, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, NA, 
1, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 4, 1, 2, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 1, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 
4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 4, 2, NA, 2.5, 4, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, NA, 2, 2.5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2.5, 4, 
2, 1, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 
4, 2.5, 4, 2.5, NA, 2, 4, 2, 2.5, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2.5, 4, 2.5, NA, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
2, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2.5, 
1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
1, 2, 4, 2, 2, NA, 2.5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1.5, 2, 4, 4, NA, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 4, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1, NA, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, NA, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 4, NA, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 4), 
    SR_1 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, 4, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2.5, NA, 1, 1, 
    2, NA, 1.5, 2.5, NA, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, NA, 1.5, NA, NA, 
    3, 1, 3, 2, 2.25, 3, NA, 1.5, 1.5, NA, 1.5, 4, NA, 1.5, 2.75, 
    1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 
    2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3.5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
    2, 2, 4, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 
    1.5, 2, 1, 3, 1.5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2.25, 3, 1.75, 1.5, 
    1.5, 1, 1.5, 4, 1, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    1.5, 2, 1, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 
    1.5, 2.5, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 2, 2.25, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 4, 1.5, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 
    1.25, 2.5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 2.5, 
    2, 1.5, 1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 2.5, 4, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1.5, 2.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 
    2, 1, 3.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2.25, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 
    1.5, 4, 2, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 
    2, 1, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1.5, 
    2.5, 4, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 
    2.25, 3, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.75, 1.5, 4, 2.75, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 1.25, 
    2.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 
    1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1.75, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 
    2.5, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 1, 
    1, 1.5, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2.25, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 1.5, 
    4, 1, 1.5, 2.75, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1.5, 2, 1, 
    1.75, 2, 1.75, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1.25, 3.5, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2), SR_2 = c(4, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, NA, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, NA, 
    1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 
    1.5, NA, NA, 1.75, NA, 3, 1.5, 1.5, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, NA, 
    2, 2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1.5, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
    4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 
    1.5, 1, 1, 1.75, 1, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 1.5, 2, 
    2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1.5, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 1.75, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 1.5, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 
    1.25, 1.5, 3, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1.5, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 
    1.5, 3, 3, 1.75, 1, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 4, 2, 
    2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1.5, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 
    1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 
    1.5, 4, 4, 1.75, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1.5, 3, 2, 1.5, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 1.25, 
    1.5, 1, 2, 1.75, 3, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.75, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 2.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1.5, 3
    ), SR_3 = c(3, NA, 2.5, NA, 1, 1, NA, 2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 
    NA, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 
    4, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 2.5, 3, 1, 1, 2.5, 
    2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 3, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
    2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 
    2.5, 3.5, 1, 4, 3, 2.5, 2.5, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 
    1, 1, 1, 3, NA, 2.5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2.5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2.5, 4, 
    1, 1, 3, 2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 1, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3.5, 
    1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, NA, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, NA, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 3, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
    2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 2, 1, 4, 2.5, 
    4, 2, 3, 3, 3.5, 4, 3, NA, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3.5, 4, 
    3, NA, 1, 1, 3.5, 4, 2, 3.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 2, 2.5, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 2.5, NA, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3.5, 2, 3, 
    3.5, 3, 2.5, 3, NA, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 
    2.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1.5, NA, 2.25, 1, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3.5, 3, 
    2.5, 3, 1.5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, NA, 1, 3, 2.5, 3, 
    2.5, 3, 3, 3, 2.5, 2, 3.5, NA, 3, 3.5, 3.5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 408L))
```

I applied this code to convert from wide to long format:

```
implong <- pivot_longer(implist,
                          cols = contains(c("_1", "_2", "_3")), 
                          names_to = c("var_name","MZP"),
                          names_sep = "_(?=[123])",
                          values_drop_na = TRUE)

implong <- pivot_wider(implong, names_from = var_name)
```

And then I need to get back to a mids-object to perform ANOVAs, but I get this error message:

"Error in as.mids(implong) : Unequal group sizes in imputation index `.imp`"

**EDIT:** My guess is that because I let mice impute entire measurement points it breaks down, i.e. in the original data set there are only two measurement points for some children whilst there are now mostly three because of the imputation. How can I fix this?
I need to compute ANOVAs on the data. Would there be any other option to circumvent this problem?

Comment: I tried this approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515598/is-it-possible-to-imput-values-using-mice-package-reshape-and-perform-gee-in-r
But I still get the same error message.